# how i ask for input in my telegram chat bot python telebot

Tags: python, input, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot

I am trying to get input from the user and send this input to all bot subscribers.

so I need to save his input in variable and use it after this in send_message method but I don't know how to make my bot wait for user input and what method I should use to receive user input

thanks :]

Comment: are you running python in command prompt ?

Comment: I manage to get input from a user and send it to all subscribers already, now I have a problem with 403 Forbidden error "user blocked...."any suggestion? I get it because use closed a chat with a bot or deleted him...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an user input, the logic is a bit different. I suppose you are using longpolling.

When the bot asks the user for input, you can just save a boolean/string in a global variable, let's suppose the variable is user_input:

You receive the update, and ask the user for input, then you set user_input[user's id]['input'] = true
Then when you receive another update you just check that variable with an if (`if user_input[userid]['input']: # do something`).

If your problem is 403 Forbidden for "user has blocked the bot", you can't do anything about it.